# Android - SimpleOnGestureListener onDoubleTapEvent consumed all onScroll event

Tags: android, gesturedetector, onscrolllistener

I extend a class from `SimpleOnGestureListener` to detect all `onScroll` events, and it capture all `onScroll` events normally if I tap the screen once. But when I double tap the screen and then scroll, the `onScroll` event will be replaced by `onDoubleTapEvent` and `onScroll` is not called. I have tried to return `false` in `onDoubleTap` and `onDoubleTapEvent` but it doesn't work. The class is show in follow.

```
public class ScrollGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        System.out.println("onScroll");
        // Do something here
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("onLongPress");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("onSingleTapUp");
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        System.out.println("onFling");
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("onShowPress");
        super.onShowPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("onDown");
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("onDoubleTap");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("onDoubleTapEvent");
        return super.onDoubleTapEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("onSingleTapConfirmed");
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }
}
```

And the output from Logcat if I double tap and then scroll it will be like follow.

```
01-06 16:01:33.268: I/System.out(10693): onDown
01-06 16:01:33.268: I/System.out(10693): onDown
01-06 16:01:33.318: I/System.out(10693): onSingleTapUp
01-06 16:01:33.459: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTap
01-06 16:01:33.459: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.459: I/System.out(10693): onDown
01-06 16:01:33.459: I/System.out(10693): onDown
01-06 16:01:33.519: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.529: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.569: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.599: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.619: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.629: I/System.out(10693): onShowPress
01-06 16:01:33.629: I/System.out(10693): onShowPress
01-06 16:01:33.649: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.679: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.699: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.719: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.739: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.749: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.769: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.779: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.809: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
01-06 16:01:33.819: I/System.out(10693): onDoubleTapEvent
```

Is there a way to fix it? Like disabling double tap? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. If you look at the documentation for SimpleOnGestureListener it says

"This implements all methods in the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener and GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener"

So try changing your code to just use OnGestureListener like this and you should get only onScroll events firing when you drag, even if you double tap.

```
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class ScrollGestureListener implements OnGestureListener {

    public ScrollGestureListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        System.out.println("onScroll");
        // Do something here
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```